# dynamic DATE in a between

Tags: mysql

I need a mySQL query that make a search that covers period from 1st september to 15th August of next year automatically.
For example, if today is 10-31-2022, I would like a between clause that covers the period 08-15-2022 to 10-31-2022.
If today is 01-03-2023, the search cover the period 08-15-2022 to 01-03-2023.
Logically I don't want to put the year manually!
Thanks for help

Comment: What did you try so far, where were you stuck?

Comment: sorry I have no idea how to do it...appreciate any example. Logically I need just the parts to put in WHERE clause

Comment: "1st september to 15th August of next year [..] 08-15-2022 to 10-31-2022" - I don't see "1st september" or "next year" in that example. Please review your question and make it consistent.

Comment: the period covers 15 august to actual date, and reset after 15 august

Comment: Are you using a date column? Because it's YYYY-MM-DD or `2022-08-15`.

Comment: So you need the range between the **last** 15th August and current date? Please edit your question and clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`current_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) function.

```
-- Note, dates are YYYY-MM-DD
where created_on between '2022-08-15' and current_date()
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/NfHS_Dcq).